# groupby on multiple columns and re-assigning results to new dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have the following type of input data say df1 :

```
idtag alpha type
1      abc   1a
1      avg   1a
1      rgw   2a
1      rrw   2a
2      rgw   2a
2      abc   1a
3      abc   1a
3      rqw   2a
```

The requirement is to retrieve the "type" and count of each "type" value for every "idtag" value into a new df2 like shown below:

```
idtag  1a  2a 
1      2    2
2      1    1
3      1    1
```

This is what I used for groupby:

```
df1.groupby(['idtag','type']).count()
```

But, I am having trouble in shaping the results into producing df2.
Appreciate the help.

Thank you.

Comment: and for you it is the question number 9 of the duplicate link :)

Comment: Thank Ben. So, I can delete this post ?

Comment: Not especially, duplicates question can redirect other users to the original post with the link at the top of the question, if someone do a research with the same key word than in your title, it will help them to be redirected :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.pivot_table(index='idtag',columns='type', values='alpha', aggfunc='count')
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked. But, I have been told that its a duplicate question. But, thank you for your help.